# Running a local dependency in WSL2

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, parcel

A beginner here. I started my journey into coding a couple of months ago and finally I have decided to set-up WSL2. I have successfully installed WSL2 together with NPM and Node.

I have created a test project to start playing with, where I have installed parcel-bundler as a local dependency using npm. The package.json file gets updated to include parcel-bundler, so all good up to here.

[package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57x5X.jpg)

However, when trying to start parcel, I get a message from my terminal saying that parcel command be found!

[terminal parcel not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7ouR.jpg)

I am pretty sure there is a little thing I am missing here, but have spent hours looking for an answer but havent been able to find anything.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated, and let me know if you need any more info from my side.

Cheers,

Alejandro

Comment: To use npm scripts, you either have to install the package globally (with the `-g` flag on NPM) or use NPX (in your case `npx parcel` in your project dir). You can also add a custom npm script in your `package.json` that runs parcel.

Comment: Thanks altareos, that seems to work. I was sure I was missing something.